# .json model convert to .h5 to use with MATLAB

Tags: json, model

i download pretrained model from this url: https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/handpose_3d/detector/full/1?tfjs-format=compressed

and now i have two files: 1)model.json 2)group1-shard1of1.bin

how can i use this pretrined model in matlab

or convert this pretrained model to .h5 model

keras_model.save('path/to/keras_model.h5')

i Try This :

```
import tensorflow as tf

json_file_path = "model.json"
with open(json_file_path, "r") as json_file:
    json_savedModel= json_file.read()
model_json = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(json_savedModel)
model_json.save("E:/Projects/Python/JSON pretrained Models/tfjs-model_handpose_3d_detector_full_1/model_HandPose.h5", save_format="hf")
```

Expecting python dict contains `class_name` and `config` as keys